# 3D graphics in wpf c# on windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to 3d Graphics and also wpf and need to combine these two in my current project. I add points and normals to `MeshGeometry3D` and add `MeshGeometry3D` to `GeometryModel3D`. Then add `GeometryModel3D` to `ModelVisual3D` and finally add `ModelVisual3D` to `ViewPort3D`. Now if i need to rotate i perform the required Transform either on GeometryModel3D or ModelVisual3D and add it again finally to the ViewPort3D. I'm running into a problems:

```
objViewPort3D.Remove(objModelVisual3D);
objGeometryModel3D.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), angle += 15));
objModelVisual3D.Content = objGeometryModel3D;
objViewPort3D.Children.Add(objModelVisual3D);
```

to rotate it everytime by 15 degrees why must i do `angle += 15` and not just `15`? It seems that the stored model is not transformed by `Transform` operation but transformation is applied only when displaying by `ViewPort3D`. I want the transformation to actually change the coordinates in the stored MeshGeometry3D object so that when i do the transform next time it does on the previously transformed model and not the original model. How do i obtain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Animation

some pseudo-code:

angle = 0
function onClick:
    new_angle = angle + 30
    Animate(angle, new_angle)
    angle = new_angle

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the position of the mesh is not transformed by the "Transform" operation. Instead the Transform property defines the world transform of the mesh during rendering.

In 3d graphics the world transform transforms the points of the mesh from object space to world space during the render of the object.

[image: object space to world space diagram]

(Image from [World, View and Projection Matrix Unveiled](https://www.maccleaner.space/recommended/?sc=090fd18d-e753-47df-9bb5-c2bb855eabc0&zn=356880544&campid=8bf45264-7683-4c88-8f38-c657cbe2fe77))

It's much faster to set the world transform and let the renderer draw the mesh in a single transform than transforming each vertex of a mesh, like you want.

Comment: thanks. However my requirement is that once rendered the user can select one or more vertices in the mesh model and drag the mouse. In that case i need to deform the rendered model accordingly and render it again. What would you suggest?

Comment: Well you can do the reverse. Take the point the user clicked on, and do the inverse transform to map back to the object space.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do angle += 15 because you're applying a new RotateTransform3D each time.

This might help:

```
public RotateTransform3D MyRotationTransform { get; set; }
...
//constructor
public MyClass()
{
     MyRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 0));

}

//in your method
MyRotationTransform.Rotation += 15;
objGeometryModel3D.Transform = MyRotationTransform;
```